# Unable to change backBarButtonItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to make my backBarButtonItem to be only `<` , without `back`. I have searched stackOverflow and found some solutions, but it stays `< back`. 
I tried this in my pushed VC:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

and also this, in my `AppDelegate`:

```
navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

But none of two helped me. Anyone knows why?
This is how I push my ViewControllers:

```
let VC = XYZViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Write this piece of code in the controller from which you are pushing to the next controller

Comment: I tried in viewDidLoad. It worked. You are pushing on click of button?

Comment: My mistake. Didnt work because I was using TabBar and tried to put this line in the viewDidLoad of one of the TabBar's "Child VCs". It should have been in the "Main TabBar VC". Thanks!